# Using anaphoric bindings within a loop macro

Tags: loops, common-lisp, hashtable

I have a construct like this

```
(loop :for c :in list-of-char-codes
      :if (gethash c hash-of-frequencies)
        :do (incf (gethash c hash-of-frequencies) 0))
```

Is there a reasonable way to avoid the redundant `(gethash c hash-of-frequencies)`, e.g., for example, using an anaphoric macro?

Comment: note that `(incf X 0)` is a nop when `X` is a number. is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, there is a bug because I tried to create a minimal example on the fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to coung only those char that are already in `hash-of-frequencies`?

```
(loop :for c :in list-of-char-codes
  :for freq = (gethash c hash-of-frequencies)
  :when freq
  :do (setf (gethash c hash-of-frequencies) (1+ freq)))
```

Or maybe you want to count *all* chars?

```
(loop :for c :in list-of-char-codes
  :do (incf (gethash c hash-of-frequencies 0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also generally avoid repetition by using `#=` and `##`, like this:

```
(loop :for c :in list-of-char-codes
      :for freq = #1=(gethash c hash-of-frequencies)
      :when freq
        :do (setf #1# (1+ freq)))
```

This is doing code insertion at read time.

Comment: I wasn’t aware the capability of this reader macros. Very impressing!

Answer (score 1):

For completeness w.r.t. other fine answers, you could also do this:

```
(defun foo (list-of-char-codes hash-of-frequencies)
  (macrolet ((hash (c) `(gethash ,c hash-of-frequencies)))
    (loop :for c :in list-of-char-codes
          :for freq = (hash c)
          :when freq
            :do (setf (hash c) (1+ freq)))))
```

Note that if you often access/modify the same hash table, it might be a good idea to define a global macro to hide implementation details.

Also, you could even use `symbol-macrolet`, but I consider this bad style, because the following injects `c`, makes the binding implicit, and will break when renaming variable `c` (you asked about anaphoric macros, though):

```
;; AVOID DOING THAT, PLEASE
(defun foo (list-of-char-codes hash-of-frequencies)
  (symbol-macrolet ((hash (gethash c hash-of-frequencies)))
    (loop :for c :in list-of-char-codes
          :for freq = hash
          :when freq
            :do (setf hash (1+ freq)))))
```

Comment: Very interesting, but I see an issue that the code gets very complex (at least for my level of understanding) and is hard to understand after a while. I guess that is a usual risk using anaphoric macros?

Comment: @MartinBuchmann Yes, apart from very specific anaphoric macros that are  hard to misuse (alet, awhen), it is better to have explicit bindings (e.g. if-let, when-let); the macrolet version is more easily understandable IMHO than symbol-macrolet, which hides things too much. I personally tend to (over)use reader macros.